# How to unstack a column to create multiple columns out of it in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have csv file which contains data in below format

| row_num | classes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0:0.2,1:0.3,2:0.5 |
| 2 | 0:0.1,1:0.5:2:0.4 |
| 3 | 0:0.4,1:0.5:2:0.1 |
| 4 | 0:0.2,1:0.4:2:0.4 |

I want it to be converted as follows:

| row_num | class_0 | class_1 | class_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 0.1 | 0.5 | 0.4 |
| 3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.1 |
| 4 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.4 |

Please help me with this transformation using pyspark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR-

```
df.select("row", F.explode(F.split("classes",",")).alias("keyValue")).select("row", F.split("keyValue",":")[0].alias("key"), F.split("keyValue",":")[1].alias("value")).groupBy("row").pivot("key").agg(F.first("value")).show()
```

Output

[image: Output]

Essentially,

1. Split the column to form an array

   `df.select("row", F.split("classes",",").alias("as_array")).show(truncate=False)`

[image: AsArray]

2. Explode it to form rows for each element in the array corresponding to column "row_num"

`df.select("row", F.explode("as_array").alias("asKeyValue"))`

[image: Explode]

3. Split key and values as separate columns

`df.select("row", F.split("asKeyValue",":")[0].alias("key"), F.split("asKeyValue",":")[1].alias("value"))`

[image: SplitKV]

4. Pivot based on Row Number

Comment: Thanks Ronak Jain, The solution is super awesome, worked in my case with actual data.